# Сервер выводящий содержимое директории на NodeJS

Tags: node.js, сервер

Как на node js написать простейший сервер, выводящий содержимое директории, похожий на Nginx?

Comment: а список файлов статический?

Comment: Периодически добавляются новые файлы

Comment: тогда это не статический сервер получается?

Comment: Получается. Если ты понял, о чем я - помоги